# Import a class from an app that is from another Django project

Tags: python, django

*Django version 1.9.7.*

My current projects structure is:

```
project1
|  etl 
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── pipeline
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── linkage.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── utils
│   │   ├── views.py
└── web
    ├── manage.py
    ├── rocket
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
```

Both `pipeline` and `rocket` are Django apps. Both `etl` and `web` are Django projects. The `web` uses local SQLite DB and the `etl` uses a remote PostgreSQL DB.

How to import `Project` class from `project1/web/rocket/models.py` into `project1/etl/pipeline/linkage.py`?

I can't move the `rocket` app somewhere else inside directory hierarchy. And I tried to import it several ways, no success.

way 1

```
$ head linkage.py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..', 'web/rocket'))
from models import Project
```

Error: `ImportError: cannot import name Project`

way 2

```
$ head linkage.py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'web'))
from rocket.models import Project
```

Error: `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

way 3

```
$ head linkage.py
from ....rocket.models import Project
```

Error: `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

way 4

```
$ head linkage.py
from rocket.models import Project
```

Error: `ImportError: No module named cris.models`

Ok, I presume there can be an error because I have a file with the same name, `models.py`, in the `etl/pipeline` directory. But even if I, just for the sake of the test, copy `web/rocket/models.py` to a different file, for example `project1/web/rocket/mytest.py`.

And try to import it:

```
$ head linkage.py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..', 'web/rocket'))
from mytest import Project
```

I receive the following error:

```
  File "/home/trex/Development/Mars/new/rocket/rocket-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
  File "/home/trex/Development/Mars/new/rocket/rocket-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Ok, some messages say that I don't have `rocket` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. So, I tried to add it inside `etl/settings/base.py` file in several ways:

way 1

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'web.rocket'
]
```

Error: `ImportError: No module named web`

way 2

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'web/rocket'
]
```

Error: `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

way 3

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rocket'
]
```

Error: `ImportError: No module named rocket`

Comment: Does your rocket folder have `__init__.py` file? This file is required if you want directory to be treated like package.

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov yes, the `rocket` folder contains `__init__.py`, I've corrected my question.

Comment: is it an option to move the rocket-app up 1 folder?

Comment: @lxer Unfortunately, I can't move it. It is a working app. Not I wrote it and it is better to not mess with it.

Comment: What is in your INSTALLED_APPS ?  it contains `'web.rocket',` ?  I also dont see a `apps.py` file ; that is automatically created when using  `./manage.py startapp`

Comment: @lxer I tried it, see my update to the question, still no success.

Comment: that last error is because you are missing 'django.contrib.sites' in installed_apps , and probably not related

Comment: @lxer the `apps.py` file is not inside `pipeline` directory. Either this app was created manually or the file was deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127122/discussion-between-trex-and-lxer).